# UTF-8 is not a valid encoding name

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, http, .net-4.8

I'm encountering an issue with an HTTP request in my .NET Framework Service.
While the code works fine in all my clients, it throws an exception in one specific case:

[image]

The error messages are displayed in Portuguese, but in English, they are as follows:

"The character set provided in the ContentType is invalid." ... "UTF-8 is not a valid encoding name."

Here's the relevant code:

```
 requestMessage.Content = new System.Net.Http.StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

 TaskAwaiter<HttpResponseMessage> response;
 try
 {
     response = HTTPClient.SendAsync(requestMessage).GetAwaiter();
 }
 catch (Exception e)
 {
     throw new CDBAPIException($"Falha POST {url}", e);
 }
 try
 {
     var result = response.GetResult();
     if (result.StatusCode != System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
     {
         throw new CDBAPIException($"Falha POST {result.StatusCode} - {result.ReasonPhrase}");
     }

     var content = response.GetResult().Content.ReadAsStringAsync().GetAwaiter();
     dynamic updates = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(content.GetResult());
```

So, what do you suggest I can do to resolve this problem?

Comment: Check your json and make sure it is valid.

Comment: Yeah, I checked and It seems valid

Comment: What specific version of Windows is this running on?

Comment: Which version of .NET is it, exact build number please. Side note: `.GetAwaiter()` and `.GetResult()` don't ever do this, use `await` instead. And dispose your objects with `using`.